# RPM installer exit code 24

Tags: rpm

Is there a list of RPM exit codes if so can I have the link? Also does anyone know what exit code 24 means from an RPM installation:

```
Installer terminated incorrectly: 24
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to most programs/utils, the RPM exit (return) codes indicate how many of the packages failed; you have to actually parse out the error text to find out what went wrong.

Comment: Its also good to note that (a) the number is capped at 255, and (b) there's no guarantee that anything over 128 will make it back tot he shell.

Comment: Even running 'rpm -Uvh' on a package already installed causes a return code of 1. FML!